# Python - wordset() function

Tags: python, string

```
test(wordset(["now", "is", "time", "is", "now", "is", "is"]) == ["is", "now", "time"])
test(wordset(["I", "a", "a", "is", "a", "is", "I", "am"]) == ["I", "a", "am", "is"])
test(wordset(["or", "a", "am", "is", "are", "be", "but", "am"]) == ["a", "am", "are", "be", "but", "is", "or"])
```

Above is what the wordset() function should behave (the test() returns a Boolean value, and it has to be True for the function inside it to satisfy the requirements)

So upon my observation, the wordset() function first takes out all the unique words in the list, and then arrange them in a order which the words with the least number of letters is in the front. And if two words have the same number of letters, then arrange them in the alphabetical order.

But I do not know how to take out all the unique words in a list.

Comment: "the words with the least number of letters is in the front" eh? `are` is before `be`. The words are in alphabetical order counting all capital letters before any lower-case letter. Sometimes know as ASCII-betical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def wordset(data):
    return sorted(set(data))
```

A set allows you to remove the duplicates from the data and sorted sorts the words as desired.